# How to detect template image in other image when angle different?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I'm new with image processing and stuck on matching different angled images. 
I'm trying to detect selected template image in captured camera image. If template image and are exactly same angle everything goes well. When both image angles different, image matching fails. 
I used EmguCV to match 2 images.
what i need to use to match two image when different angle?

This is both image same angled. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrA1j.jpg

This is both image different angled. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA6Oc.jpg

```cs
Image<Bgr, byte> source = new Image<Bgr, byte>(grayMain); // Camera image
Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>(FrameImage); // Template image
Image<Bgr, byte> lastImage = source.Copy();

using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
{
    double[] minVal, maxVal;
    System.Drawing.Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
    result.MinMax(out minVal, out maxVal, out minLocations, out maxLocations);

    if (maxVal[0] > 0.75)
    {
        Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], template.Size);
        lastImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
    }
}
pictureBox.Image = lastImage.Bitmap;
```

Comment: Image URLs don't work.

Comment: Changed new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with serch rectangle in camera image and crop this image with detected rectangle using ***AForge.QuadrilateralTransformation***. And then using last images (template and cropped image) for matching.

This is after crop image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtTgA.jpg

After croping red rectangle and doing image matching resulted this image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS5BH.jpg

Hope this help.